# What is the purpose of StatisticValues field in PutMetricData?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the purpose of `StatisticValues` field in `PutMetricData()`?

From the [PutMetricData() documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html) it is not clear how to use `StatisticValues`.

From what I saw it seems like it is applicable only when retrieving the metrics, not when publishing the metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the [`put_metric_data()` - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch/client/put_metric_data.html) shows it being used:

```py
response = client.put_metric_data(
    Namespace='string',
    MetricData=[
        {
            'MetricName': 'string',
            'Dimensions': [
                {
                    'Name': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'Timestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'Value': 123.0,
            'StatisticValues': {
                'SampleCount': 123.0,
                'Sum': 123.0,
                'Minimum': 123.0,
                'Maximum': 123.0
            },
            'Values': [
                123.0,
            ],
            'Counts': [
                123.0,
            ],
            'Unit': 'Seconds'|'Microseconds'|'Milliseconds'|'Bytes'|'Kilobytes'|'Megabytes'|'Gigabytes'|'Terabytes'|'Bits'|'Kilobits'|'Megabits'|'Gigabits'|'Terabits'|'Percent'|'Count'|'Bytes/Second'|'Kilobytes/Second'|'Megabytes/Second'|'Gigabytes/Second'|'Terabytes/Second'|'Bits/Second'|'Kilobits/Second'|'Megabits/Second'|'Gigabits/Second'|'Terabits/Second'|'Count/Second'|'None',
            'StorageResolution': 123
        },
    ]
)
```

The documentation for `StatisticValues` says *"The statistical values for the metric."*

I *suspect* that it is possible to send statistics rather than individual metrics, but I agree that I couldn't see anydocumentation about.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Combined with what the documentation said it now make sense: `CloudWatch needs raw data points to calculate percentile statistics. If you publish data using a statistic set instead`